# Facebook PHP SDK - One Access Token, Multiple Apps

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications, facebook-access-token

At the moment I am working with the Facebook API and I have a small problem (never worked with the API). I am using the latest PHP SDK 4.0 and people log into an application which saves their Access Token into a database. Users can add multiple Facebook Apps (Client IDs/Secrets) to their profile to keep their apps that perform notifications at one place.

The issue I am facing is that I can not use the access token that is retrieved during the login with the apps the users add. So my problem is that I need to request a new access token without any interaction of the user.

Maybe there is another way I don't see to use the access token that I retrieve during the login process with the Client IDs/Secrets the users add.

I always retrieve one of the following two errors when I use any pair of Client ID/Secret that a user has added. *(Which means they are not the same as the Client ID/Secret the access token during the login was created)*

**Number one**

```
Unsupported post request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api
```

**Number Two**

```
Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument
```

Here is an example of what I do need to perform.

```
// Grab an app from the database
$app = App::find($button->app_id);

// Client ID/Secret
$client_id = $app->app_id;
$client_secret = $app->app_secret;

// Grab the access token for the Client ID/Secret from Facebook
$accessToken = explode('=', file_get_contents(
    'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=' . $client_id . '&client_secret=' . $client_secret . '&grant_type=client_credentials'
))[1];

// Init the SDK and set the Client ID/Secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($client_id, $client_secret);

// Find the user
$user = User::find($request->get('user_id'));

// Create a new session
$session = new FacebookSession($user->access_token);

// If the session has been created
if ($session) {
    $canvasPage = 'http://google.com/';
    $message = 'This is a test message';
    $referrer = 'ref-for-google-canvas';

    $response = (new FacebookRequest(
        $session, 'POST', '/' . $user->id . '/notifications', array(
            'access_token' => $accessToken,
            'href'         => $canvasPage,
            'template'     => $message,
            'ref'          => $referrer
        )
    ))->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User Tokens are valid for 2 hours only. You can extend them for 60 days, but there is no User Token that is valid forever. Apps should not be able to post to the User if the user did not use the App for a longer time. That being said, you don´t use a User Token for App Notifications, check out the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications

All you need is an App Token, and that one is valid forever:

```
$app_token = $appId . '|' . $appSecret;
```

About the appsecret_proof error: You probably activated it in the App settings. Either deactivate it, or add the appsecret_proof to every API call on the server. Read more about that in the Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests

Btw, sending App Notifications is very easy without the PHP SDK, check out this article: http://blog.limesoda.com/2014/08/app-notifications-facebook-apps/ - it´s in german, but the only relevant part for you is the code anyway.